# Magento forget Password soap API

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

everyone I am new here.
 I stuck with Magento API.I am creating Magento API for my e-commerece site.I have created all API but for forget password API I am not getting any solution. I have used default forget password controller but it didn't send me an email with change password link check my code and please help me to set this forget password API.I have also search all the documents but getting any answer. I have also post my code so please refer it and let me know that where is I have mistake.

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];  
require_once ('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
            ->loadByEmail($email);
//print_r($customer);


if ($customer->getId()) {
            try {
                $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
                $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
                $customer->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
    $response['response'] = "success";
      $response['message']="Password Reset Link Has Been Sent to Your Email Please Check, Your Mail Box!";
      echo json_encode($response);
    
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                Mage::log($exception);
            }
        }else{
      $response['response'] = "failed";
      $response['message']="Please Enter a Valid Email!";
      echo json_encode($response);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i worked on forget password magento api it work fine but only difficult i find that i have to save my forget password file name to index.php. make one api folder and save it with name of index.php

```
 <?php

if(!empty($_REQUEST['email']))

{
$yourCustomerEmail=$postcode = $_REQUEST['email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->loadByEmail($yourCustomerEmail);
//echo $customer->getId();
        if ($customer->getId()) {

        try {
            $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
            $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
            $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
$result = array('action'=> 'send','statuscode'=> '200');
             echo json_encode($result);
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
//echo "Exception";
                Mage::log($exception);
        }
    }
    else
    {
$result = array('action'=> 'failed','statuscode'=> '300');
echo json_encode($result);
    }

}
else
{
$result = array('action'=> 'failed','statuscode'=> '300');
echo json_encode($result);
}
        ?>
```